# CSS: span.test or .test?

Tags: css, html

Is there any difference in:

```
#example .test{margin-top:10px}
```

And

```
#example span.test{margin-top:10px}
```

.test is totally unique, no any class with that name exists. I have been trying to use like

```
<div id="example">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <span class="test">asdfghjkl</span>
</div>
```

The first css won't work, while the second works fine. Just wondering why first wont work?
Thanks

Edit:
I found out that in the input field (in above example), i had put `float:left;`, which was causing the problem. If anyone is interested, here you can see example. If you remove  `float:left;`, it will work fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/CmXrX/1/

Comment: Could we see the rest of css?

Comment: i wanted to display some text next to input field, and by default it was showing on top. i was trying to make it in the center to the input field.

Comment: Both selectors work fine. But you can't add margin like that.

Comment: I second that, in this case the rest of your CSS actually matters. The one with the `span`. has a higher _specificity_ than the first one and CSS will give preference to the highest specificity so it is possible that you have a conflicting _more specific_ rule in your CSS document that also targets that `span`. Both of those rules should match the `span`.

Comment: Applying color instead of margin, both selector do work just fine. In general `.test` would apply to **any** _HTML element_, where `span.test` would **only** apply to _span HTML elements_.

Comment: See also: [Is element-specific CSS selector bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107522/is-element-specific-css-selector-bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in the input field (in above example), i had put float:left;, which was causing the problem. If anyone is interested, here you can see example. If you remove `float:left;`, it will work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/CmXrX/1/

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a difference.  That difference is in *specificity*.  If you have conflicting CSS rules -- two rules point to the same element but certain properties conflict -- the conflict will be sorted out by the rules about specificity.

Each type of selector has a certain number of "specificity points"  For instance:

```
Selector type          Points
-----------------------------
HTML selector          1
class selector         10
id selector            100
```

So if you had these two rules:

```
#example .test{margin-top:10px}
#example span.test{margin-top:20px}
```

the top margin would be 20px, because the second rule has a specificity of 111 (100 + 10 + 1) whereas the first has 110 (100 + 10).

My guess, therefore, is that you have a conflicting style somewhere that has 111 specificity.

Comment: I think he didn't had these two rules at the same time. So this wouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @cimnine It could be some other selector. E.g. `#ancestor .foo span`

Comment: +1 - good answer. If you're getting this issue, you definitely want to use the chrome/firebug css tool to determine what rule is overwriting your css. It makes a problem like this, very, very straightforward to debug. It will even point out the line which is causing the conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering whats conflicting, i had added `float:left;` in the input field, which was causing the problem. You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/CmXrX/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are two differences:

1. The latter will only apply, if the class `test` is applied to a `span` and no other element.
2. (and most likly more relevant in your case) the latter has a higher [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than the former.

You probably have an other rule with a higher specificity then the first selector but lower than the second. That means this other rule will override the first rule, but not the second.

Comment: Thank you for the link about specificity! Much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

yes there is a difference :

```
<div id="example">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <span><div  class="test">asdfghjkl</div></span>
</div>
```

Comment: cant put div element in span (inline element)